# StreamWriter only writes first line

Tags: c#, streamwriter

I have a C# .NET 3.5 Windows Form program with this method:

```
    private void toLog(string sLog)
    {
        richTextBox1.Text += DateTime.Now.ToString("T") + ": " + sLog + "\n";
        richTextBox1.Update();
        richTextBox1.Refresh();
        using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter("log.txt", true))
        {
            writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("T") + ": " + sLog);
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Dispose();
        }

    }
```

The idea is that I can submit log entries with it and it will write the entry to both the richtextbox and the log file.

Here's the thing... the streamwriter only writes the first time the method is called!  The richtextbox updates great.  Flush() and Dispose() were something I tried later out of desperation, but I guess the using block should handle that.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: are you sure that an exception is not being thrown and caught somewhere else?

Comment: There's probably a better way, that's why I'm posting this in comments rather than answer, but I'd try to open the log.txt as a filestream, and then copy it to the writer before i began writing.

Comment: The lines `writer.Flush()` and `writer.Dispose()` are certainly redundant.  Otherwise, I can't replicate your problem.  Which folder are you writing to?  Perhaps try writing to "My Documents" instead?

Comment: My first guess would be that an IOException is being thrown by WriteLine() and is being handled elsewhere in your code. Wrap your StreamWriter code in a try block and set a break point in a catch(IOException) block. Oh sweet irony if your logging method isn't logging an exception that it itself is throwing.

Comment: I'm sorry, I should have mentioned that originally it WAS in a try-catch block and it didn't throw an error... I reduced it down to this (minus the flush() and dispose()) to try to narrow it down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think problem could be in `StreamWriter("log.txt",`: path could be changed inside your app, so you'd better to use full path here.
Example:

```
string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
string log = Path.Combine(dir, "log.txt");
using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(log, true))
```

Comment: I will try it and report back, but it is writing out the file successfully... just only the first time.

Comment: This works!!  Can you elaborate what's going on here?  Why does it work once and then not any more?

Comment: I put my original code back in there but used a full path to log.txt, and it worked also

Comment: @MichaelNelson: you have to know that when you work with files default dir could be changed. So, I imagine that first time you write "log.txt" default dir is the one where your exe stays in; probably that dir is changed, so next time your exe searches "log.txt" in default dir, that is different from the previous one! So, remember, use ALWAYS full names to avoid problems and waste hours to find the error :) Finally, remember that you should [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if this solved (or helped to solve) your problem.

Comment: @MichaelNelson: problem is not in that part of the code, but in some other part where default dir get changed. If you use some tool like [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) you can quickly find all `log.txt` files and understand where they are, so where your app was writing them...

Comment: Thanks, and sorry about the accepted answer thing... I thought "up arrowing" the answer accepted it.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to the party, but this helped me with a similar situation and maybe it'll help someone else.

I was having the same problem where the streamwriter was only writing the first line in the file and nothing else.  I was able to fix it by using a FileStream:

```
using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open("log.txt", FileMode.Open))
{
    using (StreamWriter streamWriter= new StreamWriter(fileStream))
    { 
        writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("T") + ": " + sLog);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the example below:

```
using (StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("log.txt")) 
{
    writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString("T") + ": " + sLog);
}
```

The Flush and Dispose are not necessary to use at the end of the using block, because the will be implicity called.